# Laravel migration shows "Multiple primary key defined"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, artisan-migrate, mysql-error-1068

My Laravel migration is like below

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('account_main', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('user_sn')->primary();
      $table->string('member_username', 20);
      $table->string('login_password', 255);
      $table->integer('login_count')->default('0')->unsigned();
    });
}
```

When I ran `php artisan migrate`, it shows the following error:

> 1068 Multiple primary key

Could someone help to find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Laravel Eloquent ORM` the type `increments` will be defined as `primary key` automatically. So don't need to use `primary()` method.

**If the column is integer.**

```php
$table->increments('user_sn');
```

**If the column is string**

```php
$table->string('user_sn')->primary();
```

**If you want any other column to be unique (instead of primary key)**

```php
$table->increments('user_sn');
$table->string('member_username', 20)->unique(); // cannot contain duplicate values
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `->primary()` because already `->increments('...')` includes it.
It's like if in MySQL you write this:

```
PK INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
PRIMARY KEY(PK)
```

You are declaring two times the same primary key